# Why is simple useState initialization is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have this React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

  // Get all Players
  const getAllPlayersUrl = "http://localhost:5087/api/GetAllPlayers";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(getAllPlayersUrl).then((response) => {
      setPlayers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [playerCount, setPlayerCount] = useState(players.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`This is how many there are: ${playerCount}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to print how many initial players using `playerCount` variable. However it says it's zero:

> This is how many there are: 0

If I instead print `players.length`, it would output the correct number:

```
 <p>{`This is how many there are: ${players.length}`}</p>
```

> This is how many there are: 9

Even if I remove dependency array to keep rendering, `playerCount` still wont update:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(getAllPlayersUrl).then((response) => {
      setPlayers(response.data);
    });
  });
```

I wonder why the `useState` is not working? Is there something I am missing in my code?

Comment: You need to call `setPlayerCount` if you want to... `set` the `playerCount`

Comment: The value you pass to useState is only relevant the first time, as the default. Why use playerCount at all? Just access players.length where you need it.

Comment: I don't think I need to call `setPlayerCount` since I am not changing the playerCount. I am simply getting its initial count, which is already initialized to `player.length`

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I want to modify the playerCount in the future.

Comment: _Independently_ of the length of the list? Then why's the fact that's happening right now a problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes independent of the list. It is a problem right now because its not working, and I would like to know why.

Comment: Right now it _is_ independent of the list: you never update it, it never changes. You say that's wrong and you want it to be the length of the list, so... use the length of the list. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My main question was "why is it not working?". The answer below helped me understand that when the state was initialized, `players` was empty and I never updated it, so yes it will always be 0. That's really all that I was looking for. If I really need to just get array size then I could have just done that. But I am working on a code where I am keeping track of "Selected elements" in that array, so I can't just keep using the size of the array since "Selected elements" will change all the time. So then I ran into this issue, hence the question "why is it not working?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb with state (and props) is to avoid duplicating state values when a value can be determined entirely by another. Otherwise, you can run into issues like these, where keeping multiple states in sync can be more challenging than it needs to be.

Here, you set the initial value of `playerCount` when the component mounts:

```
const [playerCount, setPlayerCount] = useState(players.length);
```

And the component mounts only once - and at that time, `players` is the empty array - so `playerCount` becomes 0, and because you never call `setPlayerCount`, it always remains 0.

While you could fix it by calling `setPlayerCount` inside your `.then`, a better approach would be to either calculate the player count from the `players` state only when needed:

```
function App() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const getAllPlayersUrl = "http://localhost:5087/api/GetAllPlayers";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(getAllPlayersUrl).then((response) => {
      setPlayers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`This is how many there are: ${players.length}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or, if you really had to, to memoize the count depending on the `players` array (without creating additional state).

```
function App() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const playerCount = useMemo(() => players.length, [players]);
  const getAllPlayersUrl = "http://localhost:5087/api/GetAllPlayers";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(getAllPlayersUrl).then((response) => {
      setPlayers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`This is how many there are: ${playerCount}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! Although I did not use useMemo, I found a way to fix it.